# Approximation algorithm to visit all nodes in an undirected, weighted, complete graph, with shortest sum of edge weights

Tags: traveling-salesman, minimum-spanning-tree, euclidean-distance

I'm looking for an algorithm that gives a smallest value of 'travel cost' within the following constraints:

- a complete, connected, weighted graph,
- vertices are defined in 3d euclidean space,
- relatively low number of vertices (less than 500)
- no limits on how many times a node may be visited
- a fixed starting vertex
- no requirement for which vertex to end at.

I've looked at *minimum spanning tree* algorithms, but those could create sub-optimal result, because they optimize for lowest summed edge weight.

I'm suspecting this may be a variant of the traveling salesman problem and thus NP-hard. For our use case however, a good approximation will be good enough.

Comment: Define "good" approximation. MST gives a trivial 2 approximation for the TSP.

Comment: what is a 'trivial 2 approximation' ?

Comment: He means it's never more than twice the optional route. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-2-approximate-using-mst/amp/).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is a weighted graph, and $T_{OPT}$ is the optimal route you seek.

For clarity: $T_{OPT}$ is a path that connects all vertices, such that for any other path $P$ that connects all vertices, it holds that $w(T_{OPT}) \leq w(P)$.

Denote $M$ for the MST of $G$. Since $T_{OPT}$ is a subgraph of $G$ that connects all its vertices, we can say:

1. $w(M) \leq w(T_{OPT})$ - by definition of MST.

Denote $M^*$ An euler tour of $M$. Since $M^*$ visits each *edge* of $M$ exactly twice, it holds that:

2. $w(M^*) = 2w(M)$
3. $M^*$ is some path that visits all vertices of $G$, hence a path that solves your problem (although we **cannot** say $w(M^*) = w(T_{OPT})$)

Following from 1. 2. and 3. we get:

$$w(M) \leq w(T_{OPT})$$
$$2w(M) \leq 2w(T_{OPT})$$
And, since $w(M^*) = 2w(M)$
$$w(M^*) \leq 2w(T_{OPT})$$

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. However, I don't understand how it answers the question? Why is the euler tour introduced?

Comment: $M^*$ is a traversal of $G$ as requested, with a cost not more than $2 * OPT$. If you're asking "Why does the euler tour of the MST gives this approximation?" then a proof is added to the answer